# Bad Access Error

Tags: c++

Here's some code I've been working with

```
void Category::categoryPagesSet(char**&words, char**&category, char**&subset,     
int **&pages, int** &catPages)
{

int index2=1;
 int ind[getCatSize()];
for (int i=0;i<getCatSize();i++)
{
    ind[i]=1;
}
for (int i=0;i<getWordSize();i++)
{

    for (int j=0;j<getCatSize();j++)
    {
      if(strcmp(words[i], category[j])==0)
      {
          for(int j=ind[i];j<ind[i]+pages[i][0];j++)
          {
              catPages[i][j]=pages[i][index2];
              index2++;
          }
          index2=1;
          ind[j]+=pages[i][0];
      }
    }

}
}
```

I've already allocated memory for catPages in another method.

```
void Category::categoryPagesInit(char**&words, char**&category, char**&subset,                  

int **&pages, int** &catPages)
   {

int howManyPages[getCatSize()];
       int cap=0;
       int index=0;
      char**temp;
for (int i=0; i<getCatSize(); i++) {
    howManyPages[i]=0;
}
for (int i=0;i<getWordSize();i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<getCatSize();j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(words[i], category[j])==0)
        {
            howManyPages[j]+=pages[i][0];
        }
    }
    for (int k=0;k<getSubSize();k++)
    {
        if (strcmp(words[i], subset[k])==0)
        {
            howManyPages[getsubsetIndex(k)]+=pages[i][0];
        }

    }
}
for (int i=0;i<CategorySize;i++)
{
    std::cout<<howManyPages[i]<<std::endl;
}
cap=getCatSize();
for (int i=0;i<cap;i++)
{
    if(howManyPages[i]==0)
    {delete [] category[i];
        CategorySize--;
    }
}
temp=new char*[getCatSize()];
catPages=new int* [getCatSize()];
for (int i=0; i<cap; i++) {
    if (howManyPages[i]!=0)
    {
        temp[index]=new char[strlen(category[i])+1];
        strcpy(temp[index], category[i]);

        std :: cout<<howManyPages[i]<<std::endl;
        catPages[index]=new int(howManyPages[i]+1);
        catPages[index][0]=0;
        catPages[index][0]=howManyPages[i];
        std::cout<<catPages[index][0]<<std::endl;
        index++;
    }

}

delete [] category;
category=temp;
```

}

```
      catPages[i][j]=pages[i][index2];
```

keeps giving me a bad access message with error code 2.
I'm so frustrated because I don''t know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: How did you allocate `catPages`?

Comment: its for a school program. no strings allowed.

Comment: With all those references to pointers of pointers, I would actually be surprised if there were no "bad access"es.

Comment: You did not show how you allocated the second dimension of the pages array. Additionally, you are accessing the second dimension of the pages array using a 1-based index, rather than a 0-based index. That looks strange.